# Extracting a part of message from Yopmail using Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I want to Extract a Specific part in  Python Selenium. I have done it with Pyautogui but I want to do it without that is it possible?

```
https://yopmail.com/
```

put in inbox tab

```
jenniferwilks09182
```

I want to extract exactly this code it is in a separate div
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element with the ***code*** is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be visible*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

  - Using *XPATH* and `following`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='ifmail']")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[.='Your code is:']//following::div[1]"))).text)
    ```
  - Using *XPATH* and `following-sibling`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='ifmail']")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[.='Your code is:']//following-sibling::div[1]"))).text)
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Thank You Sir it Works perfectly!! Just a quick question do we need to turn off frame mode ? I think I heard something like that somewhere

Comment: @Muazam After the operations within the frame, you need to switch back [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447)'s focus to the default content using `driver.switch_to.default_content()`